# What is causing this recursion limit error?

Tags: function, recursion, wolfram-mathematica

This code produces the correct answer, but generates an error message. Why would the recursion level exceed 30?)

Thanks for your help.

```
Clear[f];
f[0] = 1000000;
f[x_] := f[x] = f[x - 1]*1.05 - 41000;

f[10]

Out[143]= 1.1132*10^6

In[144]:= f[30]

Out[144]= 1.59795*10^6
```

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: No error found. Clear your session using `Quit[]` and try again.

Comment: That's it. Actually, I didn't clear the session but the error message went away after I fiddled with $RecursionLimit a little. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's evaluate f[100]. The first rule `f[0]=...` doesn't apply, but the next one, namely `f[x_] = ...` does. We see that `x_` matches 100. So now `x` is bound to 100. The result of the right hand side is: `f[x]=f[x-1]*1.05` and since `x` is 100, we need to evaluate: `f[100]=f[100-1]*1.05` which is the same as `f[100]=f[99]*1.05`. In order to compare the two sides with `=`, we need to evalute the two sides first. To sum up, the value of `f[100]` depends on the value of `f[99]`. If go through the same steps we see that `f[99]` depends on `f[98]` which depends on `f[97]` and so on until f[0] is reached.

Now the steps described above are not necessarily the same steps that Mathematica goes through, so the number of steps might not be exactly the same as the steps Mathematica needs to go through. It might count the call to `=` as a step too [I am not 100% sure]. The actual evaluation rules are described in the documentation, but they are somewhat involved.